# Property of class being displayed differently when I print it through a breakpoint or through console.warn

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, this, breakpoints, arrow-functions

This is quite bizarre. I have an object with a boolean property. 
I want to see how it's doing so I do a `console.warn`, which gives me the expected result. However, if I put a breakpoint on the `console.warn` and display the variable through my dev tools console, I get `undefined`. What is going on?

This is what my code roughly looks like:

```
export default class {
  constructor () {
    this.myProperty = true
  }

  doStuff () {
    return {
      doSomething: (...args) => {
        console.warn('this.myProperty', this.myProperty) // will display true
        // If I put a breakpoint on the console.warn and print it through my dev tools, it will display undefined.
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: IIRC there's a bug with `this` in the repl at breakpoints in arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bergi mentioned, it looks like this is a Chrome bug: https://crbug.com/760225